# What R function can I use to use a image link as a background image in a ggplot2 bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spotify

I've been trying to create a simple program that would create a bar graph based on album lengths, with the album's cover as the background to the image. However, I cannot figure out how to turn Spotify's image link into a background image that ggplot2 can parse into a background. Spotify's get_album() simply comes with a link to an image (ex:"

https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273922a12ba0b5a66f034dc9959

"). How could I turn this into a displayable image in a ggplot2 bar graph like so:

```
ggplot(data=album_df, aes(x=rev(factor(track_names, track_names)), y=-1 * track_length)) +
  ggtitle("Songs vs length")+
    annotation_custom(rasterGrob(album_cover, 
                               width = unit(1,"npc"), 
                               height = unit(1,"npc")), 
                               -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity", color = 'NA', alpha = 0.9, width = 1, fill = 'white') +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-1 * max_track, 0)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
        ) + 
   coord_flip()
```

the annotation_custom is where I have currently stored the background image using a read as jpeg format, however this requires I first download the image, which I cannot do if I expect this to be a public website.

Comment: IN addition to my comments in your follow up question, I would like to ask if my answer provides an answer to this question here, as stated. In this case, it would be great if you could accept it, and focus on the follow up question. This way the question won't be flagged as unanswered any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are referring to when saying that you cannot download the image 'if you expect it to be a public website'. If you are referring to licensing issues, I guess any un-licensed use of the image would be of concern.

Here is a solution which downloads the image from the link to a temporary file which you can then delete if you want (note you still have the image stored as an object, and - more importantly - you are still going to use it).

I am using the picture of your avatar, which is in `png` format. For the Spotify jpeg image, use `jpeg::readJPEG()` instead.

I am using `ggpubr::background_image` because this makes this way easier than `annotate_custom`

```r
library(ggplot2)

download.file('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e01b978970939af0a188df8c28136a67?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
              destfile= 'tmp.png')                     
img <- png::readPNG('tmp.png')

# Plot with background image
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  ggpubr::background_image(img)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>