# How to turn an image link into a background image using ggplot2 without downloading the image

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

[This is a follow up to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60752269/what-r-function-can-i-use-to-use-a-image-link-as-a-background-image-in-a-ggplot2)

I'm trying to create a [shiny-app](/questions/tagged/shiny-app) that would download an image using only a link, and then display that image as a background using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) with a graph overlaid onto it. How can I either get ggplot2 to display an image using only a link or get shiny to download an image locally so I can display it without it downloading onto the user's computer?

formatting of link: https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273922a12ba0b5a66f034dc9959

code for examples:

```
ggplot(data=album_df, aes(x=rev(factor(track_names, track_names)), y=-1 * track_length)) +
  ggtitle("Songs vs length")+
    annotation_custom(rasterGrob(album_cover, 
                               width = unit(1,"npc"), 
                               height = unit(1,"npc")), 
                               -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity", color = 'NA', alpha = 0.9, width = 1, fill = 'white') +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-1 * max_track, 0)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
        ) + 
   coord_flip()
```

Currently I am just using a test image in `annotation_custom` that I have downloaded to make sure the graph functions, but I would ideally like this to be something more variable that would not mess with the user's files.

In addition, I'm not entirely sure how downloading functions with shinyapp, so if possible, I would prefer to avoid that as a whole, in favor of just accessing the link and displaying it. However, if this is not possible, I would like to know how to download something in shiny, where it would be stored(on the shiny server, on my computer, on the user's computer, etc.).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that was the custom here. The main reason I'm reasking is that I'm not sure about downloading something on shiny, and I'm trying to avoid that if possible. will it download on my computer, and force me to host a bunch of random images, or worse, force the user to download the image before it displays?

Comment: P.S. I have also removed my first comment. It would be helpful for us if you could add your thoughts of your comment to your question (and thus very briefly explain why the solution I gave in the other question does not provide a satisfactory answer and you ask a follow up question.).